Permission problem with pwm and ros2
Good afternoon, I have a problem for a project. Let me explain, I'm trying to do a lawn-mower, it's a personnal project. I'm currently using a RPi 4 4bg, It runs on raspbian (Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)), the project should run with ros2 Jazzy. I'm coding in c++ and the library "wiringPi" for a faster result (even more if I want to upgrade the project in the future). At it is written in the title my problem is concerning the pwm, I have a node to control the motor for the navigation, I tried first without pwm to have the GPIO integration and I was able to switch on/off a LED in function of the command I give, when I tried to change the intensity of the LED instead of just switch it on/off I have a permission error: "pinMode PWM: Unable to do this when using /dev/gpiomem. Try sudo?"
When I try with sudo the node works but it's outside of the workspace and can't be reach by the other nodes, so I can't give any command to this node.
I tried to change the file
/boot/firmware/config.txt

by adding the line :
dtoverlay=pwm-2chan,pin=18,func=2,pin2=19,func2=2

I also tried to change the file
/etc/udev/rules.d/99-com.rules

adding the lines:
SUBSYSTEM=="pwm*", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c '\
        chown -R root:gpio /sys/class/pwm && chmod -R 770 /sys/class/pwm;\
        chown -R root:gpio /sys/devices/platform/soc/*.pwm/pwm/pwmchip* && chmod -R 770 /sys/devices/platform/soc/*.pwm/pwm/pwmchip*\
'"

I also verified if I am on the group of GPIO and I am...
I don't know what to check or what I can do, If you can give me some ideas. If you need more explanation or more information I'll be happy to give you

Your question lacks detail but also contains a number of errors.
Firstly you are NOT running Raspbian, but apparently Raspberry Pi OS  64 bit.

Secondly WiringPi was deprecated by its author 4 years ago, and while there have been attempts to recreate it neither has reproduced the excellent documentation. WiringPi PWM REQUIRES sudo.

Thirdly You mention the kernel PWM (which WiringPi does not use or support). It IS possible to use this How can I use dtoverlay=pwm but AFAIK none of the popular libraries uses it. (My pi-gpio does.)

You can switch to pigpio.

@liaifat85 which doesn't have hardware PWM.
